# How do I replace the contents of [0][0] in a js string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str= 'String with replace string is bookingForm[0][0][seat_type]';
var $k=5;

for(var $i=0; $i<5; $i++){
     var t = str.replace(/[0][0]/g,'['+$k+']['+$i+']');

//use t below
 }
```

But `[0][0]` doesnt get replaced. What should the regex be.

Comment: Escape `[` and `]` since they are special characters in a regex (look up character classes).

Comment: And actually you don't have to escape the `]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
var t = str.replace(/\[0\]\[0\]/g,'['+$k+']['+$i+']');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/\[0\]\[0\]/g
```

You need to escape `\[`

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one instance of `[0][0]` in your string, you don't need a regex:

```
var t = str.replace("[0][0]","["+$k+"]["+$i+"]");
```

Comment: +1 I like this approach. And it will be faster (a little) to not use regex :)